# Prove that random variable is Poisson Distributed.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-process

> Assume in a certain year the number of credit obligors of a bank who are at risk of default is Poisson distributed with intensity $\lambda = 10$. Each individual obligor may actually default in that year with probability $p = 0.2$. Assume mutual independence  of the obligors. Let $X$ be the number of obligors that default in that year. Show that $X$ is Poisson distributed and determine its intensity.

I denote $N$ the number of obligors at risk. 
And by using the identity 
$$P(X = k) = \sum_E P(X = k\mid N = n)P(N = n)$$
to find the pmf I think I am supposed to arrive at the Poisson distribution. 
$P(N=n)$ is already Poisson. I am having trouble figuring out the $P(X = k\mid N = n)$ and coming up with the probabilities of the pmf which need to be summed up to yield the final Poisson.

Comment: This is a standard exercise.  I've posted answers to it here several times.

Comment: can you point me to one of your solutions.

Comment: I'll see if I can find one -- that may take some time.

Comment: Here's one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1665672/marginal-probability-derived-from-joint-probability-distribution-of-a-poisson-pr $\qquad$

Comment: @JingtaoHsu Why have you deleted your question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hintage: $\mathsf P(X=k\mid N=n)$ is the probability of $k$ 'successes' in a sequence of $n$ independent trials, where 'success' means "obligator defaults" and has rate $p$.

Do you recognise this distribution now?

---

PS: $E\equiv \{n\mid n\in\{k,\ldots,\infty\}\}$, because you cannot have more successes than trials.

---

> Thanks that makes sense. It is a binomial distribution. Now how does the multiplication of the binomial with Poisson yield Poisson?

Just substitute the p.m.f. to get: $~\sum\limits_{n=k}^\infty \dfrac {n!~p^k~(1-p)^{n-k}}{ k!~(n-k)!}\cdotp\dfrac{\lambda^n e^{-\lambda}}{n!}~$, cancel common factors, move unbound factors to the left of the sigma sign, and simplify the series with a change of variables.

The "trick" then lies in recalling the Taylor series expansion $~e^t = \sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty \dfrac{t^m}{m!}~$.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. It is a binomial distribution. Now how does the multiplication of the binomial with Poisson yield Poisson? I understand that the binomial is an approximation of the Poisson as n-> infinity and p-> 0 but still cannot see the trick there.

Comment: Just substitute the p.m.f., cancel common factors, move all unbound factors to the left of the sigma sign, and simplify the remaining series with a change of variables. The "trick" then lies in the Taylor series expansion: $e^t = \sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty \dfrac{t^m}{m!}$